# Rails 3.2 precompressing selected assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, I have the following line of code in my `<head>`, inside `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "front", :media => "all" %>
```

Which works fine in development, but when I switch to production it breaks because it's not precompiled, so I run `rake assets:precompile`, which adds a bunch of files to my public directory, also fine, but all the css and js files are names like:

- `application-digest.ext`
- `application-digest.ext.gz`
- `application.ext`
- `application.ext.gz`

Where `ext` is either `css` or `js`, and `digest` obvously varies.

Image files just come with `name.ext` and `name-digest.ext` versions.

So, when navigating to the page, I get an `ActionView::Template::Error` telling me `front.css isn't precompiled`.

Since I have different layouts for different controllers (and the `FrontController` uses the `application.html.erb` layout, if that matters), I wouldn't like to include *all* of the css or js files inside all the controller layouts, because it's just shameful waste of bandwidth.

**How do I tell rails to compile all the files inside** `app/assets` **individually?**

---

I managed to "fix" the problem using live-comilation by setting `config.assets.compile = true` inside `config/environments/production.rb`, but I keep reading everywhere that's not the best way of handling assets<sup>[1]</sup>, because it wastes a lot of resources.

The app is hosted on Heroku.

---

[1]: [official Ruby on Rails guide page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation): *"This mode uses more memory, performs more poorly than the default and is not recommended."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're precompiling assets locally then you'll need to git commit the assets so heroku will load them up. But this isn't what you want to do.

/config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(front.css, another.css, heres_a_javascript.js)
```

application.js and application.css are automatically precompiled. everything else that you're linking in application.html (or anywhere, really) needs to be precompiled here

Comment: Thanks! I just found the answer to it myself a while ago and was about to post the answer, but you beat me to it! :D